# Color Fill Conditional Formatting

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need help with writing a custom conditional formatting rule that color fills the cell based on the difference of two columns. I have attached this 
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oOFat.png) of the spreadsheet for reference.

Basically, the difference of each pair of cells in columns F and H will correspond to a color fill as shown in the color legend below. For example, the difference of F3 and H3 (100% - 100% = 0%) shows that the Obligation was met for that Appropriation corresponding to that row so H3 is highlighted in green.

However, for the difference of F9 and H9 (90% - 76% = 24%) shows that the Obligation was NOT met for that Appropriation corresponding to that row so H9 is highlighted in red.

Please let me know if there is a way to do this besides individual color filling cells. This will be very helpful in future work.

Comment: like (for Range H2:H10) `=F2>H2` Red, and `=F2<=H2` Green

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I would set this up. It's essential to have the rules ordered as shown in the image for them to apply correctly.

Based on your screenshot, it seems like there's supposed to be a yellow highlight if the Actual value is <10% below the Goal value. Your question didn't specify that, but I've added it in -- you can ignore it if it's not needed and the red/green rules will work as you expect.

[image: Example of conditional formatting rules]